# How to create a collapsable menu using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to build a code snippet html page, I am using bootstrap framework.

My code looks like blow

#### HTML

```html
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
    <div class="list-container">
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush" id="snippets">
            <h3 class="list-group-item-heading">Code Snippets</h3>
        </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

#### JS Code

```js
<script>
    $( document ).ready( function () {
        for ( var index = 0; index < snippets.length; index++ ) {
            $( "#snippets" ).append( '<li class="list-group-item"> <div id="snippet_name" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#codesnippet">'
        + snippets[index].Name + '</div> <div id="codesnippet" class="collapse codesnippet javascript">'
        + '<pre><code class="javascript">'
        + snippets[index].Code + '</code></pre></li>' );

         }
    } );

</script>
```

I am not sure what I am missing here. The 2nd row collapse is not working here as expected.
For Example if I have two snippets with below structure

```
[
  {
    "name" : "alert",
    "code" : "alert('message')" ,
  },
  {
    "name" : "console",
    "code" : "console.log(message)",
  }
]
```

I am getting two rows as `alert` and `console`. When I click at `alert` its collapsing and showing `alert('message')` code but when I click at `console`, I cant see its code. But when I inspect `console` section, I can see that code and I can also print this object with out any issues.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Upload full code please, I need to know which value did you assign to snippets variable

Comment: Your html isn't valid. <ul> elements can only have <li> elements as children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're creating `<li>` elements with a `for` loop, you must make each `id` unique. One way is by appending the `index` value from your `for` loop to the `id`.

Also, you're using uppercase letters for 'Name' and 'Code' instead of lowercase which is used in your json.

Finally, you're missing a closing `div` tag which I added before the ending `<li>` element.

```
    $( document ).ready( function () {
    for ( var index = 0; index < snippets.length; index++ ) {
        $( "#snippets" ).append( '<li class="list-group-item"> <div id="snippet_name' + index + '" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#codesnippet' + index + '">'
    + snippets[index].name + '</div> <div id="codesnippet' + index + '" class="collapse codesnippet javascript">'
    + '<pre><code class="javascript">'
    + snippets[index].code + '</code></pre></div></li>' );

     }
} );
```

Hope that helps.